# Python Selenium Iframe issue on Bing

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping

I am using selenium driver with python 3.6 and am looking to search for images of coffee cups and download the first image. However, I want the bigger image and the site url so I have selenium driver click on the image and open up the frame. When I try to download the image I get an error that no such element exists. I've tried the two scenarios below

```
driver.switch_to_frame('#OverlayIFrame')
driver.switch_to_frame(driver.find_element_by_selector('#OverlayIFrame'))
```

also  tried pulling the first element in the frame to see whats there and nothing comes back. I am not sure what I am doing wrong but any help would be great.

```
bing_url = 'https://www.bing.com/'
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get(bing_url)
time.sleep(4)
# select the search box and enter a search condition
search_box = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="sb_form_q"]')
search_box.send_keys('coffee cups', Keys.ENTER)
# click on the images tab
images_tab = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//* 
[@id="b_header"]/nav/ul/li[2]/a')
images_tab.click()
select_first_image = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="mmComponent_images_1"]/ul[1]/li[1]/div/div/a/div/img')
select_first_image.click()
# gives error that no such element exists
image_url =  driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="mainImageWindow"]/div[1]/div/div/div/img')
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this.If it works for you.

```
select_first_image = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@class='cico br-pdMainImg']")
select_first_image.click()
image_url =  driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@class='br-pdItemName br-standardText']").text
print(image_url)
driver.execute_script("window.open('{},_blank');".format(image_url))
```

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution

```
driver.switch_to_active_element()
```